# Anchor SuggestionPopup to TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-popupwindow

I have a problem with a custom `PopupWindow` associated with a `TextView` with the method `setSuggestionPopup`.

When I click in the `TextView` and my layout scrolls up so that the `TextView` is not covered by the virtual keyboard my custom popup doesn't scroll and it covers the `TextView`.

Is there a way to anchor it to the `TextView` so that they are both scrolled as if they were a single object?

I associate the `PopupWindow` to `TextView` like that:

```
popupBinding = PasswordPopupBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()));
View suggestionView = popupBinding.getRoot();
PopupWindow suggestionPopup = new PopupWindow();
suggestionPopup.setContentView(suggestionView);
binding.passwordTextView.setSuggestionPopup(suggestionPopup);
```

Comment: It may be helpful to show some relevant code.

Comment: @LarsH i have updated the question with the code